# Showing that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+...\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-1}$ is divergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

> How to show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+...\frac{1}{n}\right)}$ diverges?

I used Ratio test for this problem and this is the result: $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{(n+1)+\frac{(n+1)}{2}+...+1}\right)= 1$$
Then I thought using abel or dirichlet test. But I couldn't solve it.

Comment: The first equation doesn't correspond to the equation in the title. I guess the title equation is the good one

Comment: Depending on the level of rigor that you're expected, the sum is approximately $\ln(n)$.  If you can approximate the error, this may be enough.

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+n%3D1+to+inf+of+1%2F%28H_n+n+%29) claims that the series diverges using the comparison test, although it doesn't tell us what series we would need to use the comparison test with.

Comment: If you accept that $1+\frac12+\frac13+\ldots+\frac1n \approx \ln n$, then the integral test would tell you $$\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n\left(1+\frac12+\frac13+\ldots+\frac1n\right)}\approx \int_2^N\frac{1}{x\ln x}dx\approx \ln \ln N.$$

Comment: Use the fact $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\le1+\log n$.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool However, the error in the logarithm approximation (times $n$) might affect the integral test a little bit.  One just needs to be careful (especially if this were to converge).

Comment: Try to multiply and divide both sides and you should get $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{n}}{n^{2}}$, where $H_{n}$ is the harmonic mean of the first $n$ natural numbers.

Comment: Can you show that $nH_n\sim n\log n$?

Answer (score 4):

Your sum is

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n H_n},$$

where $H_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$ is the nth harmonic number.

Since $1/x > 1/(k+1)$ for $x \in [k,k+1]$,

$$\ln n = \int_1^n \frac{1}{x} \,dx \geq \sum_{n=2}^{n+1} \frac{1}{k} = H_{n+1} - 1 > H_n - 1.$$

Now use the comparison test.

Comment: I you seek for a divergent lower bound, you need an upper bound for $H_n$.

Answer (score 1):

First, We need a lemma.

### Lemma:

For $n>1$, 
$$1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{2^n-1} < n$$

This could be checked easily with induction.

---

To prove the question we use Cauchy Condensation Test, and see that its equal to show $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+ ... +\frac{1}{2^k}$$ is divergent.

It can be checked easily that:

$$\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{2^k}} > \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{2^{k+1}-1}}$$

Now we apply our lemma for $k\geq 2$ and see:

$$\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{2^k}} > \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{2^k}+...+\frac{1}{2^{k+1}-1}} > k+1$$

hence:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{2^k}}} =  \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{2}} + \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{2^k}}}  > \sum_{k=3}^{\infty}{k}$$

Since the left hand side of inequality is divergent, the other side is so. Finally by Cauchy Condensation Test we see that the we have proved the divergence.

Answer (score 0):

First note that
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{k}}  \le 1 + \sum\limits_{k = 2}^n {\int_{k - 1}^k {\frac{{dt}}{t} } }  = 1 + \int_1^n {\frac{{dt}}{t}}  = 1 + \log n,
$$
for all $n\geq 1$. Then for all $N\geq 3$,
\begin{align*}
& \sum\limits_{n = 1}^N {\frac{1}{{n\sum\nolimits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{k}} }}}  > \sum\limits_{n = 3}^N {\frac{1}{{n\sum\nolimits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{k}} }}}  \ge \sum\limits_{n = 3}^N {\frac{1}{{n(\log n + 1)}}} \\ & \ge \sum\limits_{n = 3}^N {\frac{1}{{n(\log n + \log n)}}}  = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n = 3}^N {\frac{1}{{n\log n}}} 
\\ &
 \ge \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n = 3}^N {\int_{n}^{n+1} {\frac{{dt}}{{t\log t}}} }  = \frac{1}{2}\int_3^{N+1} {\frac{{dt}}{{t\log t}}} \\ & = \frac{{\log \log( N+1) - \log \log 3}}{2} .
\end{align*}
This shows that the series diverges.